# Adding input fields dynamically in javascript using class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I have a couple of fields that I want to duplicate dynamically when the user clicks on the Add button and then take the fields data. I have found a number of tutorials online such as [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtS14dXwvwE&t=669s) where a state is used to dynamically create new input fields and record the data. However, my application is inside a class and I would like to find the equivalent version to achieve the same inside a class.
My code is as follows

```
class SerialQRScanClass extends React.PureComponent{
    

export const getTextFieldForSmall = (
  label,
  placeholder,
  value,
  onChange,
  error = false,
  helperText = '',
) => (
  <TextField
    fullWidth
    label={label}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    error={error}
    helperText={helperText}
    margin='none'
    size='small'
  />
);


handleChangeFromSerials(v) {
    console.log(v);
    //this.props.setSerialRangeFrom(v);
    //this.checkFromToSerials();
  }


xyz(): JSX.Element {

    return (
      <Paper elevation={3} className='abc'>
        <Grid container alignItems='flex-end'>
          <Grid item className='bcd'>
            {getTextFieldForSmall(
              <Typography variant='caption'>Title</Typography>,
              'Serial start',
              1000 || '',
              (e) => this.handleChangeToSerials(e.target.value),
              false,
              'Wrong serial' || '',
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
```

The new code that Im trying to create using UseState is as follows

```
class SerialQRScanClass extends React.PureComponent {

export const getTextFieldForSmall = (
  label,
  placeholder,
  value,
  onChange,
  error = false,
  helperText = '',
) => (
  <TextField
    fullWidth
    label={label}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    error={error}
    helperText={helperText}
    margin='none'
    size='small'
  />
);

protected handleChangeFromSerials(v) {
    console.log(v);
    //this.props.setSerialRangeFrom(v);
    //this.checkFromToSerials();
  }
    protected xyz(): JSX.Element {
        const [serialRegistrationTracker, setserialRegistrationTracker] = useState([]);

    const handleAdd = () => {
      const addNewField = [...serialRegistrationTracker, []];
      setserialRegistrationTracker(addNewField);
    };

return (
      <Paper elevation={3} className='abc'>
        <Button onClick={() => handleAdd()}> ADD NEW FIELD </Button>
        {serialRegistrationTracker.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <Grid container alignItems='flex-end'>
                <Grid item className='bcd'>
                   {getTextFieldForSmall(
              <Typography variant='caption'>Title
              </Typography>,
                    'Serial start',
              1000 || '',
              (e) => this.handleChangeToSerials(e.target.value),
              false,
              'Wrong serial' || '', 
                 )}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
           </div>
          );
        })}

}
}
```

I want to repeat the input field everytime I click the 'ADD NEW FIELD' Button.

Comment: I don't know if something got dropped when the code was copy/pasted into the question, but this code appears to be incomplete, and has what appears to be object properties mixed right in the middle of the JSX return. Can you fix your code so it could be considered a [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese Is this better?

Comment: Yes, better. What is the issue with the code you are using *other than* that you can't use React hooks in non-React function components? Can you include your types/interfaces to help complete the [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese I have made more changes, please check it now

Comment: What are `Props` and `State`? What is `getTextFieldForSmall` and `handleChangeFromSerials`? What is this odd `protected xyz(): JSX.Element {` at the top of the class?

Comment: @DrewReese Ive made the changes. Im trying to take the input from text field and then process that input. I want to create multiple such fields everytime the user click the add new field button and store the values and process it. Dynamic text field input on button click.

Comment: I understand that part of your post. I'm asking about the parts of your code that are unclear, syntactically incorrect, or missing as part of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useState` hook, and all React hooks, can not be used in a React class component. Just use regular React state. I suggest declaring state as an array of objects where each object has a GUID to uniquely identify it. In the `handleAdd` handler append a new object with new id and empty data. In the `handleChangeFromSerials` handler map the previous state array to the next state array, and for the matching element object *by id* shallow copy it into a new object reference and update the data.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Grid, Paper, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

interface Props {}

interface SerialRegistrationTracker {
  id: string;
  data: string;
}

interface State {
  serialRegistrationTracker: SerialRegistrationTracker[];
}

class SerialQRScanClass extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  state = {
    serialRegistrationTracker: []
  };

  handleAdd = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      serialRegistrationTracker: [
        ...prevState.serialRegistrationTracker,
        {
          id: nanoid(),
          data: ""
        }
      ]
    }));
  };

  handleChangeFromSerials = (id: string, data: string) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      serialRegistrationTracker: prevState.serialRegistrationTracker.map((el) =>
        el.id === id
          ? {
              ...el,
              data
            }
          : el
      )
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Paper elevation={3} className="abc">
        <Button onClick={this.handleAdd}>ADD NEW FIELD</Button>
        {this.state.serialRegistrationTracker.map(({ data, id }) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <Grid container alignItems="flex-end">
              <Grid item className="bcd">
                <Typography variant="caption">Title</Typography>
                <textarea
                  value={data}
                  placeholder="Sample start form"
                  maxLength={10000}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    this.handleChangeFromSerials(id, e.target.value)
                  }
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit adding-input-fields-dynamically-in-javascript-using-class]